# java HashMap to file and file to HashMap outputs null

Tags: java, null, hashmap, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Hey guys I'm pretty new to developping and at this forum and wanted to create a login mirror. I had to use BlueJ because of my teacher and yeah,.. that's propably not one of the best ways to learn writing I guess (the version we have to use in school not even shows misstakes before compiling)  (I personally started writing with Eclipse).

My problem is that the output I get from my hasMapReader just is null, after I "saved" the HashMap in a new file and "wrote" it in an other HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Serializable> userAcc = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
userAcc.put(name, value);

otherClass.hashMapSaver(userAcc, hashMapFile = new java.io.File(location));



    public HashMap<String, Serializable> hashMapSaver(HashMap<String, Serializable> map, java.io.File file){
            try{   
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
    s.writeObject(map);

    s.close();
    f.close();

    }catch (IOException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return map;
    }




   HashMap<String, Serializable> userAcc2 = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
   otherClass.hashMapReader(userAcc2, new java.io.File(hashMapFile));
```

(userAcc2 is in the third "main" class)
then the hashMapReader in the other class:

```
 public HashMap<String, Serializable> hashMapReader(HashMap<String, Serializable> map2, java.io.File file){

    try{   
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);  
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);          
    map2 = (HashMap<String, Serializable>) s.readObject();
    f.close();
    s.close();


    }catch (IOException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
       return null;
    }  catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
     c.printStackTrace();
     return null;
    }
    return map2;
}



System.out.println("userAcc2: " + userAcc2.get(name));
System.out.println("HashMap Keys: " + userAcc2.keySet());
```

but console just prints out:

*userAcc2: null;
HashMap Keys: []*

An other problem I think, is that the file may gets replaced every time I start this program.

I'm trying to solve this nearly a week for now.

Thanks :),

Comment: You introduce null in your catch blocks. (1) Is an exception being thrown? (2) Is the method in fact being called? And where are the variables referenced in the print lines created?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `map2` is an argument in `hashMapReader` yet, within that method you perform the following assignment:

```
map2 = (HashMap<String, Serializable>) s.readObject();
```

That that updates the `map2` variable, but not the object referenced by `map2`. Since `hashMapReader` returns `map2`, the following change would fix your problem:

```
userAcc2 = otherClass.hashMapReader(userAcc2, new java.io.File(hashMapFile));
```

As a side note, the `map2` argument is entirely unnecessary since you are not using object being passed anyway. Something slightly cleaner would be:

```
public HashMap<String, Serializable> hashMapReader(java.io.File file){
    HashMap<String, Serializable> map2 = null;
    try{   
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);  
        ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);          
        map2 = (HashMap<String, Serializable>) s.readObject();
        f.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return map2;
}

...
userAcc2 = otherClass.hashMapReader(new java.io.File(hashMapFile));
```